When I trying to up my project to Vercel this error kept happening
[here is deployment errors](https://i.sstatic.net/M6zl5ftp.png)
I was trying to up my project to the vercel.
here is my package.json
{   "name": "caboodles-ui",   "version": "0.1.0",   "private": true,   "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 14052",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 14052",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "postinstall": "npm run prepare",
    "eslint": "eslint \"**/*.+(js|jsx|ts|tsx)\"",
    "eslint:fix": "eslint --fix \"**/*.+(js|jsx|ts|tsx)\"",
    "prettier": "prettier --check \"**/*.+(js|jsx|ts|tsx|json|yml|yaml|md|css|scss)\"",
    "prettier:fix": "prettier --write \"**/*.+(js|jsx|ts|tsx|json|yml|yaml|md|css|scss)\"",
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged && npm run build"   },   "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/server": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.7",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.7",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.1.7",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^6.1.7",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^6.1.7",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.10",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.6",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.1",
    "@mui/system": "^5.10.10",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.14.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.6",
    "@types/node": "18.11.9",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.80",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.9",
    "apexcharts": "^3.44.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.9",
    "eventemitter3": "^5.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lottie-react": "^2.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "next": "13.0.5",
    "next-progress": "^2.2.0",
    "next-pwa": "5.5.4",
    "next-seo": "^5.14.1",
    "nookies": "^2.5.2",
    "notistack": "^2.0.8",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.1",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.4",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.39.6",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
    "react-query": "^3.39.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-state-sync": "^3.1.4",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "typescript": "4.9.3",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"   },   "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^17.1.2",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.1.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.9",
    "@types/react-lottie": "^1.2.6",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.24",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.10",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.9",
    "eslint": "8.22.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.5",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-css-modules": "^2.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-mui-path-imports": "^0.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.10",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^2.0.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^13.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "sass": "^1.54.5"   },   "lint-staged": {
    "./*/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
      "npm run prettier:fix",
      "npm run eslint:fix"
    ],
    "*.{json,md}": [
      "npm run prettier:fix"
    ]   },   "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }   } }

